# Operation based on command line parameter in R

Tags: c#, r, .net, command-line, parameters

I'm trying to execute an R script based on a command line parameter passed by a C# script.

As an example, in C# I created a method that I call like this:

```
 int x = 1;
 RunFromCmd(path, scriptPath, path.Replace('\\', '/'), x);
```

where x is my parameter

In my R script I'm saving the parameter like this:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
```

then I need to execute a part of the code or another based on the args[1]  (if it is 1 or 2)

```
if(args[1]==1) {
  an execution
} 

if(args[1]==2) 
{
  another execution
}

 print("hello")
```

If I remove the comparison it works fine, while when I try to compare the args[1] with the number 1 it skips the if condition.

What's the matter?

I tried to transform as.numeric the args[1] or to use string but no way

Thanks in advance

EDIT

Made some changements in the if condition.

Assuming I'm passing 1 as argument, it print only hello and skip both the if conditions

Comment: The arguments are strings not numbers.  So use if(args[1]=="1")

Comment: @jdweng, I don't think that's it: `"1" == 1` returns true, R will cast it appropriately (for better or worse). MrCaptainAlex, when you say *"it skips the if condition"*, do you mean that neither `an execution` nor `another execution` execute? or that it executes the "else" clause instead of (as you expect) executing the first?

Comment: @jdweng Already tried, didn't solved

Comment: r2evans I'm editing the post because I made a little error while copying the code

Comment: From `(path, scriptPath, path.Replace('\\', '/'), x)`, it seems as if `x` (which should be 1 or 2) is not the first argument, but likely the second. Have you tried `if (args[2] == 1)`? If not, then try adding `cat(capture.output(dput(args)), "\n")` to the beginning of your script and pasting its output in your question.

Comment: Since you're coming from C# ... are you aware that indexing in R is 1-based, not 0-based? If your `x[1]` is intending to get the second argument, then it could be this.

Comment: Trying the solution args[2] didn't worked. Adding the cat command at the beginning of the R script and saving it to a variable in C#, the variable is populated like this: "function (name)  .Internal(args(name)) \r\n"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233851/discussion-between-mrcaptain-alex-and-r2evans).

Comment: I meant to put the `capture.output(.)` *after* the `args <- commandArgs(..)` assignment.

Comment: I don't know how C# is sending that ... perhaps you need `RunFromCmd` to send `x` as a string instead of as an integer?